# Is it possible to pass a delegate on multiple levels?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

I want to do something like:

```
class A
{
     void Print(string message)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
     }
     B.Method1(Print);

}

class B
{
     delegate void Print(string message);

     void Method1(Print PrintOutput)
     {
         C.Method2(PrintOutput);
     }   
}

class C
{
     delegate void Print(string message);

     void Method2(Print PrintOutput)
     {
         PrintOutput("Bye!");
     }   
}
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is that my first class (A) is a class in a WinForms app which calls a method from a class from a different project, but in the same solution, which in return calls another method from another class (again different project) in the same solution. I would like to call a method in class A from class C.

If I try to do this the way I've written above, I receive a compiling error in class B saying that the best overloaded match for this method has some invalid arguments.

Comment: Why are you declaring the delegate in both classes?

Comment: If you suggest using in class C something like void Method2(B.Print PrintOutput) then unfortunately it's not possible for me to add a reference to the project of which class B is a part of.

Comment: Why declare a delegate at all? Why not use the built in `Action<string>` delegate?

Comment: Because I didn't know about Action :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe the Action delegate is what you're looking for:

```
public class A
{
    void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
    }

    public A()
    {
        new B().Method1(Print);
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void Method1(Action<string> PrintOutput)
    {
        new C().Method2(PrintOutput);
    }
}

public class C
{
    public void Method2(Action<string> PrintOutput)
    {
        PrintOutput("Bye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you! indeed, Action was what I was looking for, but didn't know it exists :)

Comment: `Action` is not a keyword, it's just a delegate type like any other.

Comment: Yup, my bad...apologies :s

Answer (score 2):

You get the error message because you declared two different delegate types with the same signature, and then you try to access the `C.Method2` with the delegate declared in `class B`

To avoid this, you have to explicitly declare that the delegate type accepted in class `B` is of type `C`:

```
public void Method1(C.Print PrintOutput)
{
    var C = new C();
    C.Method2(PrintOutput);
}
```

Or, the better approach would be to accept a generic `Action<string>` instead of creating your own:

```
class B
{
     public void Method1(Action<string> PrintOutput)
     {
         var C = new C();
         C.Method2(PrintOutput);
     }
}

class C
{
     public void Method2(Action<string> PrintOutput)
     {
         PrintOutput("Bye!");
     }   
}
```